# How to add an app to a page via Graph API? (with Koala gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

Ok, I have a Rails app using the Koala gem. I have manage_pages permissions and I'm able to successfully get the user's pages and access_tokens.

I want to add an application with a Page Tab to one of the user's pages. Basically the equivalent of going to an app's profile, [clicking "add to page" and selecting a page](http://cl.ly/1r3S2X241W081x1C2229) to add it to.

I don't see where in the Graph API this is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the manage pages permission using the Graph API you can install a profile_tab at the end of the current list of installed tabs for a page by issuing an HTTP POST request to PAGE_ID/tabs with a Page Access Token

https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_PAGE_ID/tabs/create/?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&access_token=YOUR_TOKEN

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing it like this:

```
koala = Koala::Facebook::API.new( page_token )

tabs = koala.get_connections("me", "tabs")

koala.put_connections("me","tabs", {app_id: new_app_id }, {api_version: "v2.3"})

tabs = koala.get_connections("me", "tabs")
```

inspect tabs and search for the new added tab.

If you want to delete the tab:

```
koala.delete_connections("me","tabs", {app_id: id_to_be_deleted }, {api_version: "v2.3"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey answer that u gave is right.I have  also done by same way.
https://graph.facebook.com/pageid/tabs?app_id=applicationid&method=POST &access_token=Page access token`
With this facebook request I am able to add application profile page to my facebook fan page.But I am add comment to that fan page.But that new throught manually and wanted to add comment box inside the fan page.Can I used comment plugin ,how to used that?By application in fbml.